# How to nest some values in an javascript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i am having an object like this

```
let details = { 
          name: "Dhanush",
          age: "25",
          gender: "Male",
          email: "dhanush@gmail.com",
          mobile: "9999999999"
}
```

I am getting the above value from the API. Here I have nest email and mobile key/value pair into a contactDetails key as an object mentioned below.

```
let result = {
          name: "Dhanush",
          age: "25",
          gender: "Male",
          contactDetails: {
              email: "dhanush@gmail.com",
              mobile: "9999999999",
          }
}
```

Any idea to achieve this dynamically

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: You could create a function like this and call it with your object: `const nest = ({ name, gender, age, ...contactDetails }) => ({ name, gender, age, contactDetails })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let details = {
  name: "Dhanush",
  age: "25",
  gender: "Male",
  email: "dhanush@gmail.com",
  mobile: "9999999999"
}

const {
  email,
  mobile,
  ...rest
} = details

const formatted = {
  ...rest,
  contactDetails: {
    email,
    mobile
  }
}

console.log(formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are trying to achieve:

```
let result = {
    name: details.name,
    age: details.age,
    gender: details.gender,
    contactDetails: {
        email: details.email,
        mobile: details.mobile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new result object from your details object and assign the proper values. like this:

```
let result = {
          name: details.name,
          age: details.age,
          gender: details.gender,
          contactDetails: {
              email: details.email,
              mobile: details.mobile
          }
}
```